# Paypal Subscription Details

Tags: paypal, subscription

Can you help me. I need to know if PayPal has an API call to get subscription details like the enddate of the subscription?

I do the request to PayPal and get the response, 

SUCCESS
transaction_subject=Name20
payment_date=10%3A42%3A50+Mar+28%2C+2014+PDT
txn_type=subscr_payment
subscr_id=I-MWMMATTBSY2M
last_name=jls
....


but I need details from suscription as enddate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using Standard Subscriptions and the "response" you're referring to would be an Instant Payment Notification (IPN)..??

Unfortunately, the standard subscriptions system doesn't have any API's to access details directly.  You could switch to Express Checkout and the Recurring Payments API, though, and this would give you access to API's to obtain details and manage the profiles programatically.

If you're working with PHP you can setup Express Checkout and Recurring Payments very easily using my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).

The flow you'll be setting up would be as follows...

1) Call SetExpressCheckout to obtain a token and redirect the user to PayPal.  The SEC request will also include a ReturnURL which is where PayPal sends the user after they've signed in and agreed to continue.  You also need to make sure to include the Billing Agreement parameters in your SEC request so that the token you get will be compatible with recurring payments.

2)  The user ends up back at your ReturnURL, and this is where you'll call GetExpressCheckoutDetails to obtain details about the buyer that the system now knows since they've signed in.  This gives you info like the payer's name, email, address, etc.  It also gives you the Payer ID you'll need for the final request.

3)  Right after obtaining the details via GECD you'll call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile to finalize the subscription profile creation.

Comment: I understand, but I have other question, When paypal return to my page, it  send me some data in querystring.. 
(http://MyPageReturn?tx=9VX76418A19607352&st=Completed&amt=16.00&c..) but when is a free trial suscription, I get nothing in query string, so, what data does paypal send me when is a free trial suscription? and how do I get data? thanks for your answer..